# Laravel auto-login when visiting to website again

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, authentication

Hi i Hope you all are fine.. i'm new to laravel.
I want that if once user is logged in after successful registration to website and visit my website after sometime or some days even every time of visit he **login to website automatically**. 
I have search lot of stuff but it not work to me. please suggest me to a better way to do this
Here is my website link [Salebaba](https://salebaba.com)

This is custom website and delevloped in Laravel

Comment: You can create  Remember me  on click this store the cookies then user have to no need  to login every time

Comment: could you show some stuff or brief example of this. im very glad for help :) @LalitKumar

Comment: Please have a look  on   that https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-do-remember-me-function-at-login-option-in-laravel-5example.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Remembering Users**

> If you would like to provide "remember me" functionality in your
>   application, you may pass a boolean value as the second argument to
>   the attempt method, which will keep the user authenticated
>   indefinitely, or until they manually logout. Your users table must
>   include the string remember_token column, which will be used to store
>   the "remember me" token.

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password], $remember = true)) {
    // The user is being remembered...
}
```

You may also set Laravel cookie session lifetime to 10080 min (7 days) as an example

Comment: where to add cookie session lifetime

Comment: `config/session.php`
Then run `php artisan config:clear`